# Переделать приложение WindowsForms + Selenium WebDriver для работы с сервера(C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

Есть приложение WindowsForms(суть такова: вводишь логин и пароль, программа заходит на сайт, забирает нужны данные). Данные выводятся в TextBox'ы.
Как ее переделать так, чтобы она работала не в браузере пользователя, а хостинге/сервере. Как реализовать работу на сервере(как загрузить и запустить), стоит ли вообще использовать Selenium Web Driver?

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void START_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IWebDriver web;
            string LOGIN = LoginBox.Text; 
            string PASSWORD = PassBox.Text; /
            web = new ChromeDriver();

            try
            {
                web.Navigate().GoToUrl("ссылка"); 
                web.FindElement(By.XPath(" //input[@id='login']")).SendKeys(LOGIN); 
                web.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password']")).SendKeys(PASSWORD); 
                web.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='sub-btn']")).Click(); 
                web.FindElement(By.LinkText("кнопка")).Click(); 
                web.FindElement(By.LinkText("кнопка")).Click(); 
             }
             catch { }  //убрал некоторые детали если что
```

Comment: Селениум для управления внешним браузером, но можно научить приложение работать с сайтом напрямую, для этого есть класс `HttpClient`. Только в этом случае вам нужно будет не нажимать на кнопку в форме, а сабмитить форму с данными методом HTTP POST, читать куки из ответа и использовать их при последующих запросах. В этом случае само приложение будет взаимодействовать с веб-сервером напрямую, без браузера. Грубо говоря, получится свой самописный движок-браузер.

Comment: Спасибо, для этого подойдет обычный хостинг или VPS/с поддержкой asp.net или что-то подобное?

Comment: VPS точно подойдет.